# Proof involving transfinite induction on ordinals

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals

Prove that if $\omega\le \alpha, 0\le n <\omega$ and $0<m<\omega$ then $(\alpha+n)*m=\alpha*m+n$

My attempt is as follows:

By induction on $n$, the base case when $n=0$ is trivial so, looking at the successor step we set $n=\delta+1$ so then $(\alpha+(\delta+1))*m=(\alpha*m)+(\delta+1)=(\alpha*m)+n$ so the step when $n$ is a successor holds.

Now when $n$ is a limit ordinal we have that $(\alpha+n)*m=(\alpha+\sup_{\epsilon<n}\{\epsilon\})*m=(\alpha*m)+\sup_{\epsilon<n}\{\epsilon\}=(\alpha*m)+n$ as required thus the statement is true and has been proved?

Was just wondering if anyone could check if the above is correct and if not would be able to provide where i have gone wrong and how to fix it

Comment: How do you justify the step when $n$ is a successor? Your claim  "So  $(\alpha +(\delta +1))\cdot  m= \alpha \cdot m +(\delta +1).$..." is just what you need to prove.

Comment: is that not just from the definition of multiplication for ordinals?

Comment: since $\delta+1$ is another unique ordinal?

Comment: Particular case: Prove that $(\omega +1)\cdot 2=\omega \cdot 2+1.$ The def'n of $x\cdot y$ for ordinals $x,y$ is the ordinal that is isomorphic to the dictionary order on $y\times x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) In the theory of ordinals, $\omega$ is not a variable, but a constant. It is the least infinite ordinal. Therefore $n < \omega$ means that $n$ is finite. In particular, it is not a limit ordinal. So you don't even need to worry about what happens when $n$ is a limit ordinal. (And also, your proof is by ordinary induction, not transfinite induction).

(2) your proof for non-limit $n$ is wrong. You say

> $(\alpha+(\delta+1)*m=(\alpha*m)+(\delta+1)=(\alpha*m)+n$

But showing that $(\alpha+(\delta+1))\cdot m$ is indeed $(\alpha\cdot m)+(\delta+1)$ is what you are supposed to do. What you already know (by supposition) is only that $(\alpha+\delta)\cdot m = \alpha\cdot m +\delta$. From there you have to prove that it holds for $\delta + 1$ as well, not just state it.

**Edit** (removed incorrect statements User1006 pointed out)

Comment: @User1006 - Thank you. I have removed the inaccurate claim.

Comment: I don't understand how i would show this is that not just from the definition of multiplication for ordinals?, and how come it is just by normal induction?

Comment: It's normal induction because you are inducting on $n$ and $n$ is limited by the assumptions to finite ordinals, so no transfiniteness occurs. User1006 has provided the needed method to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\alpha >\omega>n$, it can be proved as:
\begin{align}
(\alpha +n)\cdot m&=\underbrace{(\alpha +n)+(\alpha +n)+\cdots+(\alpha +n)}_{m}
\\
&=\underbrace{\alpha +(n+\alpha)+\cdots+(n+\alpha) }_{m}+n
\\
&=\underbrace{\alpha +\alpha+\cdots+\alpha }_{m}+n
\\
&=\alpha \cdot m+n
\end{align}